# How to append inner-html from a div to a target div?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to append html from a div to a target div. Can it be done by jQuery?

I have tried some jQuery. but it didnt respond.

```js
$(".categories_box").clone().end().appendTo(".target-div");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories_box">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Technology <span>37</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Lifestyle <span>04</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Service <span>29</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Food <span>15</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Architecture <span>09</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Adventure <span>44</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="target-div"></div>
```

I have tried to append the entire `"<ul>"` to the "target-div". But it didn't respond yet.

Comment: This will append whole div to the target div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(".categories_box").clone().appendTo(".target-div");` 
 The `.end()` is used to

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and
>   return the set of matched elements to its previous state.
>
> Most of jQuery's DOM traversal methods operate on a jQuery object
>   instance and produce a new one, matching a different set of DOM
>   elements. When this happens, it is as if the new set of elements is
>   pushed onto a stack that is maintained inside the object. Each
>   successive filtering method pushes a new element set onto the stack.
>   If we need an older element set, we can use end() to pop the sets back
>   off of the stack.

So what you really need is to append the cloned elements.

*** UPDATE ***

To append only the children:

`$(".categories_box").children().clone().appendTo(".target-div");`

Comment: This is working but it copies whole div to the target div .. I need to copy innerHTML of the div.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.html() from jquery](http://api.jquery.com/html/) like this:

```
$(".target-div").html($(".categories_box").html());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(".target-div").html($(".categories_box").html());
```

The only you have to change your js code.

Comment: Its working. but I have marked an answer already. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//$(".categories_box").clone().end().appendTo(".target-div");
$(".target-div").append($(".categories_box").clone().find('ul'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories_box">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Technology <span>37</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Lifestyle <span>04</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Service <span>29</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Food <span>15</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Architecture <span>09</span></a></li>
       <li><a href="JavaScript:void(0)">Adventure <span>44</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
        
<div class="target-div"></div>
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: \"\" is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 27,
  "colno": 11
}